# Regex to search for string?

Tags: c#, regex

The strings I want to match will always contain the phrase "START". How can I only return matches that contain this phrase?

Here is my current pattern:

`"(?<=utm_name=potato\" rel=(\"carrot\"|\"*\") >)(.*?)(?=</a>)"`

Here is the string input:

`&amp;utm_name=potato" rel="" >[START] This is a sentence.</a>&#32;<span class="beans">&amp;utm_name=potato" rel="carrot" >[START] This is another sentence.</a>&#32;<span class="beans">&amp;utm_name=potato" rel="carrot" >[FALSE] Do not match this sentence.</a>&#32;<span class="beans">`

Desired output:

`[START] This is a sentence.`

`[START] This is another sentence.`

Current output:

`[START] This is a sentence.`

`[START] This is another sentence.`

`[FALSE] Do not match this sentence.`

Comment: Replace `.*` with `.*START.*`?

Comment: @juharr Here is the result, with your proposal: ([link](https://i.imgur.com/pH8W8b5.png))

Comment: Why don’t you just search for \[START\].*?\.

Comment: @Marathon55 For two reasons. It only returns partial matches of the desired outputs, and also returns undesired matches. ([link](https://i.imgur.com/ZrPGcvx.png))

Comment: Oops...There are supposed to be backslashes in front of the square brackets \\[START\\].*?\.

Comment: @Marathon55 Thank you very much for your help. The output from `@"\[(?i)START].*?(?=</a>)"` fully meets my expectations.

Comment: @Hui Zui Please see my submission for a way to use .IndexOf()  with two search phrases to find a solution this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to use `.IndexOf()` passing the search arguments on a string.

Start out with creating an `int` to hold the index value of search phrase, as well as the index value of where you think the phrase is going to end.

The substring you desire lies between the index of your initial search phrase, and the index of your last search phrase. In this case, the last phrase ends on another search string, i. e. `</a>`.

```
string test = "&amp;utm_name=potato\" rel=\"\" >[START] This is a sentence.</a>&#32;<span class=\"beans\">&amp;utm_name=potato\" rel=\"carrot\" >[START] This is another sentence.</a>&#32;<span class=\"beans\">&amp;utm_name=potato\" rel=\"carrot\" >[FALSE] Do not match this sentence.</a>&#32;<span class=\"beans\">";

string searchString = ">[START] ";  //start after this
string endSearchString = "</a>"; //end before this
```

Ensure that when you are creating the index of the initial search phrase, you add the length of that search phrase.

```
//find the index of them within the sample test string
int indexOfInitial = test.IndexOf(searchString) + searchString.Length;
int indexOfEnding = test.IndexOf(endSearchString);
```

Create a length for the new substring.  This is going to be the value of the index of the last search phrase subtracted by the index of the initial search phrase.  You now have what is necessary to create a substring.

```
//create a length for substring
int length = indexOfEnding - indexOfInitial;
//create desired substring out of search string and length between start and end phrases
string desiredSubstring = test.Substring(indexOfInitial, length);
```

For an example of how this works with your string input heres a code demo:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //create sample test string
    string test = "&amp;utm_name=potato\" rel=\"\" >[START] This is a sentence.</a>&#32;<span class=\"beans\">&amp;utm_name=potato\" rel=\"carrot\" >[START] This is another sentence.</a>&#32;<span class=\"beans\">&amp;utm_name=potato\" rel=\"carrot\" >[FALSE] Do not match this sentence.</a>&#32;<span class=\"beans\">";
    //create strings you are searching for
    string searchString = ">[START] ";
    string endSearchString = "</a>";

    Console.WriteLine("String:");
    Console.WriteLine(test);

    //find the index of them within the sample test string
    int indexOfInitial = test.IndexOf(searchString) + searchString.Length;
    int indexOfEnding = test.IndexOf(endSearchString);

    //create a length for substring
    int length = indexOfEnding - indexOfInitial;

    string desiredSubstring = test.Substring(indexOfInitial, length);

    //desired result 1
    Console.WriteLine("\nResult 1:\n\n{0}", desiredSubstring);

    //Take of everything from the indexOfEnding
    test = test.Substring(indexOfEnding+endSearchString.Length);
    Console.WriteLine("\nString:\n{0}\n",test);    

    //change the search strings if needed
    //endSearchString = "</ a >"; //notice the spacing changing

    //find the index of them again within the new substring
    indexOfInitial = test.IndexOf(searchString) + searchString.Length;
    indexOfEnding = test.IndexOf(endSearchString);
    //create a length for substring
    length = indexOfEnding - indexOfInitial;
    //desired result 2
    Console.WriteLine("\nResult 2:\n\n{0}", test.Substring(indexOfInitial, length));
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: I can certainly see the potential. Thank you.